# Как создать картинку из текста?

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно создать из текста картинку (объект типа `Image` или `Bitmap`), на которой будет отрисован данный текст заданным шрифтом (и больше ничего).

Так же нужно сделать перенос слов, чтобы текст вмещался в нужную мне ширину.

**UPD:**
Извините, но я не понимаю, чего вам не хватает. Я задал конкретный вопрос. Я не понимаю, что в нем не понятно. Есть какой то текст типа `string`, мне нужно создать из него изображение типа `Image` или `Bitmap`, причем нужно, чтобы слова переносились. То есть чтобы текст влезал в заданную ширину.

Comment: Winforms/Wpf? И чем обычный текст не устаивает? Каковы цели?

Comment: @Arheus, да хоть консольное приложение. Цели - получить из текста картинку :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap

Comment: Использовать или [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext(v=vs.110).aspx) или [Graphics.DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,  TextRenderer.DrawText не подходит (именно мне), так как не хочется цеплять библиотеку винформ туда, где она не будет использоваться по прямому назначению, а вот Graphics вполне подходит. Оформите в ответ?

Comment: @Arheus, у меня черный прямоугольник получается :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько способов для вывода текста на картинку.

Метод [Graphics.DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx). Требует подключения библиотеки `System.Drawing.dll`.

```
string text = "Какой-нибудь весьма длинный текст, не влезающий в картинку по длине, поэтому требующий переноса";
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);

// Создаём битмап с нужными размерами и форматом пикселей.
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(200, 100, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 10))
{
    // Заливаем фон нужным цветом.
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect);

    // Выводим текст.
    g.DrawString(
        text,
        font,
        Brushes.Black, // цвет текста
        rect, // текст будет вписан в указанный прямоугольник
        StringFormat.GenericTypographic
        );
}
```

Метод [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext(v=vs.110).aspx). Требует подключения библиотеки `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

```
Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(200, 100, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2))
using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 10))
{
    g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

    // Заливаем фон нужным цветом.
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect);

    // Выводим текст.
    TextRenderer.DrawText(
        g,
        text,
        font,
        rect,
        Color.Black, // цвет текста
        TextFormatFlags.WordBreak // включаем перенос слов
        );
}
```

У обоих методов большое количество параметров, позволяющих гибко настраивать вывод текста.

Comment: Сделал я так... уже несколько часов как. Через graphics. А теперь сижу и думаю, как сделать обводку. ))

Comment: @iRumba - задавай новый вопрос.

Comment: задал ) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546597/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9