# Перевести текст в картинку с обводкой

Tags: c#, .net

Написал функцию, которая текст превращает в `Image`.

```
System.Drawing.Image ImageFromText(string text, Font font, System.Drawing.Brush foreGround)
{
    var img = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    using (var grp = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        grp.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        grp.Clear(Color.White);
        var size = grp.MeasureString(text, font);
        grp.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        grp.DrawString(text, font, foreGround, new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 100), sf);
        var gp = new GraphicsPath();

        gp.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, font.SizeInPoints, new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 100), sf);
        var rec = gp.GetBounds();
        var p = new Pen(foreGround, 1)
        {
            LineJoin = LineJoin.Round
        };
        grp.DrawPath(p, gp);
    }
    return img;
}
```

Вот тут строка `gp.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, font.SizeInPoints, new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 100), sf);` превращает текст в `Path`. проблема в том, что размер шрифта в данном случае не соблюден. В вызове функции я задаю фон со шрифтом Verdana и размером `36pt`. В итоге текст и обводка должны наложиться друг на друга, но этого не происходит.

Вот что получилось:

[image: Вот что получилось]

Зачем такие трудности, спросите вы, ведь можно сделать и заливку и обводку через `Path`. Дело в том, что по планам размер шрифта должен будет выбираться автоматически (от заданного минимального до максимального), чтобы текст идеально вписался в заданную область. У `Graphics` есть метод `MeasureString`, который покажет мне размер получившегося текста. А вот `Path` такого не может. Да и к тому же текст, который на картинке крупнее имеет реальный размер (визуально сопоставил с буквой М в ворде).

---

Вопрос, как заставить `GraphicsPath.AddString()` рисовать текст с правильным размером?

Comment: Угу, я как раз хотел предложить использовать `GraphicsPath`. Подумаем...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, отбой... Сам спросил - сам ответил ) Разобрался короч.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а нет, не отбой... не работает это... не тот результат возвращает эта функция. В общем нужен способ перевести pt в em

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, похоже, проблема все же имеет другие корни. em же относительный размер. но так как при инициализации шрифта я таки пишу его размер, значит эти единицы считаются относительно 1. Для DrawString. А вот для AddString нет, похоже. По крайней мере опытным путем я выяснил, что если указать для первого размер 24, то для второго нужно указать 32, чтобы они были одинаковы. Но просто взять и вставить нужный коэффициент я не могу, вдруг он на других машинах будет другим.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, снова разобрался ))

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался.

```
var emSize = grp.DpiY * font.SizeInPoints / 72;
gp.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, emSize, new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 100), sf);
```

Первая строка - это конвертация pt размерности в em. Не спрашивайте, что за 72, я не знаю. Взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292812/font-in-graphicspath-addstring-is-smaller-than-usual-font

Comment: 1 дюйм = 72 типографских пункта